# PHP PDO - Exclude a particular row from a query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working with PDO to connect to my database. I would like to perform a query and exclude a particular row from my query only. I'm not sure how to do it.

From the suggestions I got from another question, I posted this is my current solution right now but it doesn't work

```
$queryProfileCode = $dbh->prepare("SELECT profile_code FROM tableBusinessProfiles WHERE profile_code = ? AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tableBusinessProfiles WHERE profile_code = $businessProfileIDUrl)");
$queryProfileCode->bindValue(1,$profileCode);
$queryProfileCode->execute();
$resultTableProfileCode = $queryProfileCode->fetchAll();
```

I couldn't find how to exclude a particular record from my query.

Comment: What record needs to be excluded? What conditions does it match?

Answer (score 1):

your query should be

```
SELECT 
profile_code 
FROM tableBusinessProfiles 
WHERE 
profile_code != $businessProfileIDUrl
```

or

```
SELECT 
profile_code 
FROM tableBusinessProfiles 
WHERE 
id NOT IN ($businessProfileIDUrl);
```

The MySQL **"not equal to"**  operaters are **!= and <>****

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you try to achieve? The problem is the query?

Do you want to `get ALL profile_codes FROM tableBusinessProfiles WHERE profile_code DOES NOT EQUAL TO $businessProfileIDUrl`?

The query could then be:

```
SELECT profile_code FROM tableBusinessProfiles WHERE profile_code != $businessProfileIDUrl
```